# Android: Bypass Low Power Audio Player (LPA Player) on Galaxy S3

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I've got a Music Playing app which is having trouble on some Galaxy S3's.

At the end of a track, the player switches audio output from the headphones to the speaker for a few seconds, or else the volume might jump up momentarily.

I've had some advice that it may be to do with the new gapless API's, and Samsung's LPA Player. At the end of a track, `setNextMediaPlayer()` is called, and I think this is where Android switches between the default Media Player and the LPA Player (provided the LPA Player is available). Because the LPA Player strips all the effects, I think it messes with the audio stream, and the phone gets confused.

I'd like to find a way to bypass the LPA Player. I had some advice to prepare a MediaPlayer with a >60s mp3 to consume the LPA Player, but it didn't seem to work for me (I don't have a test device for this bug myself), and it seems a pretty bad solution (I have to ship the app with an mp3, and presumably waste system resources holding a prepared MediaPlayer for the lifecycle of the app).

I'm open to suggestions, and also - who can I contact at Samsung or Google to have this issue formally addressed?

Thanks.

Comment: For an informal chat about the issue with Google guys, you could try #android on freenode. Ops in that channel are from Google.